# How do I safely resume with HTTP clients after Coordinated Restore at Checkpoint?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, apache-httpclient-4.x, firecracker

"Serverless" infrastructure like AWS lambda makes use of Coordinated Restore at Checkpoint to improve startup time of java programs.

AWS documentation states that

> The state of connections that your function establishes during the initialization phase isn't guaranteed when Lambda resumes your function from a snapshot. Validate the state of your network connections and re-establish them as necessary. In most cases, network connections that an AWS SDK establishes automatically resume. For other connections, review the best practices.

Spring docs mention

> Leveraging checkpoint/restore of a running application typically requires additional lifecycle management to gracefully stop and start using resources like files or sockets and stop active threads.

I am wondering what I need to do when using `HttpClient` from the standard library or `CloseableHttpClient` from Apache to deal with this.
Let's say I am performing an HTTP request before the snapshot to perform client priming. What do I need to do in the `afterRestore` hook to avoid any network related problems?

```
@Override
public void beforeCheckpoint(org.crac.Context<? extends Resource> context) throws Exception {
    var response = performPrimingRequest(httpClient);
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
}
```

A connection that was established will be closed, and the destination IP might not be valid anymore. So I assume recreate the client or at least clear the connection pool. Is this possible with the standard JavaClient? Anything else required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting this answer as research result, I havent used CRaC before.

[CRaC](https://openjdk.org/projects/crac/) looks like a very thin layer and from [this](https://github.com/CRaC/org.crac/blob/master/src/main/java/org/crac/Core.java#L141) line I understand that http client or any thread will get a nudge to go on.

I would suggest to put a retry logic. After restore, probably the http connection will **hang** first then get **timeout** but in second try you may get a response. This connection may require authentication that will need another refresh on other parts but you got the picture.

On the other hand Micronaut looks like having more [investment on CRaC](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-crac/latest/guide/#checkpointSimulator). And for spring boot you can check this [demo](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot-crac-demo/tree/main).

> So I assume recreate the client or at least clear the connection pool. Is this possible with the standard JavaClient? Anything else required?

Yes probably a good refresh will be required after restore. You can use actuators like the [doc says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/application-context-services.html#refresh-scope) and here is [another sample](https://github.com/OlgaMaciaszek/crac-db-refresh-scope) which helps about db connections in spring.

Comment: I also did some further testing and it seems like most HTTP libs detect the stale connection and will perform a retry pretty quickly.